# How to show an image from a GridView in an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, imageview

```
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> gridView, View view,
            int pos, long id) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.create().show();        

    }
});
```

When I try to run this code, after I click on an item, I get an exception:

[image]

I don't want to remove view from its parent. I just want to show the image in an `AlertDialog`. Can someone give me a hint how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> gridView, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(gridView.getContext());
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            view.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            builder.setView(imageView);
            builder.create().show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show Image then You can set

```
builder .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Then you don't need to setView.

So remove this line:

```
builder.setView(view);
```